# Using Google+ API causes HttpAccessTokenRefreshError

Tags: python, google-api, google-authentication

I want to use server-side communication with the Google+ API to retrieve the current user's profile information. I log in the user according to the Google example for python:

```
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'profile', 'email'],
    code)
```

Then I call the Google+ API:

```
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('plus', 'v1', http = http_auth)
google_request = service.people().list(userId = 'me', collection = 'visible')
result = google_request.execute()
```

This thows the following error:

```
HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

Does anyone have an idea what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the correct method `people().get()` instead of `people().list()`

At first I wanted to delete the question because the topic seems silly but I copy-pasted the wrong API call from a code sample on Github and therefore I can imagine that others run into this issue as well.